# In QGIS, is there a way to have the same layers in multiple groups

Tags: qgis

I have a large project with at least 80 layers of various types and growing. These data in these layers changes occasionally and I need to repeat outputs of numerous combinations of layers.

Currently, I have to record each layer I use for each output and turn the layers on as required and sometimes I need to change the rendering order.

I know about the standard groups in QGIS, but for my needs I would have to duplicate dozens of layers and put these into individual groups in the required order to generate my numerous outputs. Another way would be to create different projects for each, but that's just as bad and difficult to ensure the layers keep in sync. There must be a better way of doing this, but I've not found one yet. Anyone any ideas?

I'm using QGIS 3

Comment: How is your data stored? SQL? Shapefile?

Comment: It's mainly shapefiles with a few georeferenced raster maps

Comment: I am having trouble understanding your problem but are you aware that you can easily duplicate a layer by right clicking the layer name and choose "Duplicate"

Comment: I do know about duplication and I guess that would be one way of doing it. It means rethinking my project layout, but its' perfectly doable, thanks.

Comment: @PeterCornelissen - What about creating a "master" group which contains the standard set of layers. You can _right-click_ this group and select the `Save as Layer Definition File...` option and save the file somewhere. Now you can go to the menubar at the top and add a duplicated version of the same group (and all its layers) from: `Layer > Add from Layer Definition File...`.

Comment: I use that method to create new projects, but unfortunately the groups are different in just about every case so that doesn't really help.